# Modifying Makefile to account for new .cpp and .h file?

Tags: c++, makefile

So I'm trying to include the LodePNG library into my existing C++ project -- I have a bunch of .h files and one `.cpp` file with a `main()`, `Scene.cpp`. I have the `lodepng.cpp` and `lodepng.h` files in my project directory.

Here's my current `Makefile`:

```
CC = g++
ifeq ($(shell sw_vers 2>/dev/null | grep Mac | awk '{ print $$2}'),Mac)
    CFLAGS = -g -DGL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES -I./include/ -I/usr/X11/include -DOSX
    LDFLAGS = -framework GLUT -framework OpenGL \
        -L"/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Libraries" \
        -lGL -lGLU -lm -lstdc++
else
    CFLAGS = -g -DGL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES -Iglut-3.7.6-bin
    LDFLAGS = -lglut -lGLU
    FLAGS += -O3
    FLAGS += -std=c++11
    FLAGS += -D_DEBUG -g Wall
endif

all: main 
main: scene.o 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o scene scene.o $(LDFLAGS) 
scene.o: Scene.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c Scene.cpp -o scene.o
clean: 
    $(RM) *.o scene
```

What do I need to add to this to use LodePNG in my project?!

Thanks.

Comment: Your `main` target should be `scene`. A target should always create a file of that same name.

Comment: Sorry, what does this mean? Running `make` with the code in the OP successfully generates the `scene` executable.

Comment: It does but make doesn't know that happened. make believes it generated the `main` file (but it didn't). And make is going to recompile `scene` every time you run `make` even when `scene.o`/`Scene.cpp` hasn't changed as a result of that. It isn't related to your question just a general makefile "issue".

Comment: I see. So should the lines `all: main` and  `main: scene.o` be changed to `all:scene` and `scene: scene.o` respectively?

Comment: Correct. Which also lets you use the automatic variable `$@` which is the target being built. So `-o $@`.

Comment: Excellent, makes sense. I'm still not able to add LodePNG to my Makefile though. I've added the lines  
`lodepng.o: lodepng.cpp lodepng.h` and 
`$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c lodepng.cpp -o lodepng.o` above the `clean` line, and I'm getting a `missing separator` error.

Comment: That error is *almost always* because you used spaces on the rule line instead of a tab.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72612/discussion-between-ryan-yu-and-etan-reisner).